# Associativity of ->

Tags: haskell

For monad bind operator, I can find that it's associativity is left from `ghci` using:

```
λ> :i (>>=)
class Monad (m :: * -> *) where
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  ...
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
infixl 1 >>=
```

But the same doesn't work for `->`:

```
λ> :i (->)
data (->) a b   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Prim’
instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Functor ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

Where exactly it's associativity is documented (Link to Haskell report is welcome, but I was not able to find there in my attempt) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Haskell 2010 Language Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-630004.1) at §4.1.2 (Syntax of Types), page 38:

> A function type has the form `t1 -> t2`, which is equivalent to the type `(->) t1 t2`. Function arrows associate to the right. For example, `Int -> Int -> Float` means `Int -> (Int -> Float)`.

Here you can find the context in the report:

[image: Image showing the context in which the quote above was taken]

Comment: It seems to be in section 10.5: context-free syntax. `type`, `btype`, and `atype` productions, and maybe a bit more.

Comment: @dfeuer Nope, page 38 from the link.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the specific productions.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers apply to the standard language, in which `->` is the only infix type operator and so may be considered pure syntax.  However, GHC has the `TypeOperators` extension, so then it's a bit more subtle.  [From the manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#infix-tycons):

> - Function arrow is `infixr` with fixity 0. (This might change; I'm not sure what it should be.)

Given this it might be considered a bug that it doesn't list the fixity with `:i`. (Edit: Made a [ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10145#ticket).)

Answer (score 2):

The -> operator is right associative. Here is a place where that's documented:
https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application

There are two reasons why :i (>>=) and :i (->) are different:

- (>>=) is a function, but (->) can only occur in the type of a
  function
- (>>=) is actually defined somewhere (for each Monad type),
  but (->) is built-in

Why does right associativity makes sense? Whenever a function has an argument which is a function itself, you want to make this explicit. Take for example "map":

```
:t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Map is a function which takes two arguments, the first is of the type (a -> b), so it is clearly a function, and the second is of the type [a]. It returns [b]. We could of course (since -> is right-associative) read Map as having the type:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

While this is precisely the same type, we now read map as taking one argument, which is a function of the type (a -> b), and returning another function, which is of type ([a] -> [b]). These two ways to understand the type of map are described in the partial application article above.